# How can I avoid including debug code in source control with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, preprocessor

When testing our iOS app, my team and I need to disable SSL certificate validation.

At present, we are using a hard-coded `#define`:

```
// In Prefix.pch
#define ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTS

// Elsewhere
#ifdef ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTS
// Code to disable SSL certificate validation
#endif
```

As a result, we have to remember to remove the `#define` every time we release a new version.

Ideally we would like to find a way to enable a flag in Xcode that would not be checked into source control.

I have discovered that this is possible using application arguments (`[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments`); however this is potentially exploitable since an attacker could find a way to provide the argument in question to the app before it is launched.

Is there another way to set this up in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the Other C Flag in your build settings like -DDEBUG=1 in the debug settings and in the release settings set this to -DDEBUG=0. Then in your prefix file define your debug macro like this.

```
#if DEBUG
#define ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTS 1
#else
#define ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTS 0
#endif
```

I do it in this way. Here is a screenshot if you want to know where to set the -DDEBUG option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try defining an environmental variable on your dev machines, like IOS_PROJ_ALLOW_INVALID_CERT=1 (and make sure it's NOT defined on your build machine).

Then modify your project's preprocessor macro build settings to set the ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTS macro to the value of your $(IOS_PROJ_ALLOW_INVALID_CERT) env var.